# The block is displayed on top of the upper block when it is first loaded and is fixed when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

The block is displayed on top of the top block when it is first loaded and is fixed when the page is refreshed. In the mobile version of the site is the same situation. Sometimes displays correctly.
The site itself is connected to WordPress, optimized using Page Speed ​​ninja.
Changed the settings for Page Speed ​​ninja, still without result. 
How can I fix this?

[Screen of a mobile version, when site's open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPKRO.png)

[Screen of mobile version, after refreshing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwNq8.png)

HTML code of section:

```
<section id="protfolio_sec">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12">
                <div class="title_sec">
                    <h1>&nbsp</h1>
                    <h1><?php echo $redux['sportft'];?></h1>
                    <h2><?php echo $redux['sportfd'];?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="all-portfolios">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 ">
                        <div class="single-portfolio <?php echo $redux['sportf12'];?>" onclick="window.open('projects/project1')">
                            <div class="sngl_pricing">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $redux['sportf1img']['url'];?>" height ="270" alt="">
                                <h3>
                                    <?php echo $redux['sportf1'];?>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo $redux['sportf11'];?>
                                    </p>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-portfolio <?php echo $redux['sportf22'];?>" onclick="window.open('projects/project2')">
                            <div class="sngl_pricing">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $redux['sportf2img']['url'];?>" height ="270" alt="">
                                <h3>
                                    <?php echo $redux['sportf2'];?>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo $redux['sportf21'];?>
                                    </p>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-portfolio <?php echo $redux['sportf32'];?>" onclick="window.open('projects/project3')">
                            <div class="sngl_pricing">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $redux['sportf3img']['url'];?>" height ="270" alt="">
                                <h3>
                                    <?php echo $redux['sportf3'];?>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo $redux['sportf31'];?>
                                    </p>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-portfolio <?php echo $redux['sportf42'];?>" onclick="window.open('projects/project4')">
                            <div class="sngl_pricing">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $redux['sportf4img']['url'];?>" height ="270" alt="">
                                <h3>
                                    <?php echo $redux['sportf4'];?>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo $redux['sportf41'];?>
                                    </p>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="all-portfolios">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 ">
                        <div class="single-portfolio <?php echo $redux['sportf52'];?>" onclick="window.open('projects/project5')">
                            <div class="sngl_pricing">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $redux['sportf5img']['url'];?>" height ="270" alt="">
                                <h3>
                                    <?php echo $redux['sportf5'];?>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo $redux['sportf51'];?>
                                    </p>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-portfolio <?php echo $redux['sportf62'];?>" onclick="window.open('projects/project6')">
                            <div class="sngl_pricing">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $redux['sportf6img']['url'];?>" height ="270" alt="">
                                <h3>
                                    <?php echo $redux['sportf6'];?>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo $redux['sportf61'];?>
                                    </p>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-portfolio <?php echo $redux['sportf72'];?>" onclick="window.open('projects/project7')">
                            <div class="sngl_pricing">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $redux['sportf7img']['url'];?>" height ="270" alt="">
                                <h3>
                                    <?php echo $redux['sportf7'];?>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo $redux['sportf71'];?>
                                    </p>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-portfolio <?php echo $redux['sportf82'];?>" onclick="window.open('projects/project8')">
                            <div class="sngl_pricing">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $redux['sportf8img']['url'];?>" height ="270" alt="">
                                <h3>
                                    <?php echo $redux['sportf8'];?>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo $redux['sportf81'];?>
                                    </p>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post_btn">
                    <div class="hover_effect_btn" id="hover_effect_btn">
                        <a href="projects/projects" data-hover="view more post"><span><?php echo $redux['sportfb'];?></span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#protfolio_sec ul.filter {
    color : #2e2e2e;
}
#protfolio_sec ul.filter li {
    color : #666666;
    cursor : pointer;
    display : inline-block;
    font-family : Century Gothic;
    font-size : 14px;
    margin-right : 5px;
    padding : 15px 35px;
    position : relative;
}
#protfolio_sec ul.filter li:hover {
    color : #36BFF3;
}
#protfolio_sec ul.filter li.active {
    border-bottom : 1px solid #00AFF0;
}
#protfolio_sec .all-portfolios {
    margin-top : 20px;
    margin-left : -10px;
}
#protfolio_sec .single-portfolio {
    float : left;
    margin-bottom : 10px;
    width : 277px;
}
#protfolio_sec .single-portfolio:hover .img_hoverlay {
    display : block;
}
```

JS code after the footer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/appear.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/showHide.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.show_hide').showHide( {
            speed: 1000,
            easing: '',
            changeText: 1,
            showText: 'View',
            hideText: 'Close'
        }); 
    });
</script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $('.counter').counterUp({
            delay: 10,
            time: 1000
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    //Hide Overflow of Body on DOM Ready //
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    });

    // Show Overflow of Body when Everything has Loaded 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("body").css("overflow", "visible");        
        var nice=$('html').niceScroll({
            cursorborder:"5",
            cursorcolor:"#00AFF0",
            cursorwidth:"3px",
            boxzoom:true, 
            autohidemode:true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you really need three versions of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

It could have to do with the scrolling / easing jquery. Eliminate each jquery for your test (not the jquery.min.js) but the personalized ones and test if it does the overlapping during the first load.

Also test by eliminating all the personalized jqueries (nicescroll, easing, scrolling-nav) all at once and test what is happening, by adding them back on one-by-one. Somewhere it stops from reaching the end of its timing for the scrolls, I think.

-----> just for better practices

Try not using the space as a padding in the following way:

> `<h1>&nbsp</h1>`

instead in css create a style

```
.pb_1 {
    padding-bottom: 1em; // e.g.
}

.pb_2 {
    padding-bottom: 2em;  // if you want more space
}
```

On your html file

```
<div class="title_sec  pb_1">  <!--  add your padding styles here  -->
<!-- eliminate this part  <h1>&nbsp</h1>  -->
```